Can a Circle of Stars Druid wear a star map and simply touch it to use it as a focus?
I am a druid/monk multiclass. Am I able to use my quarterstaff 2 handed and wear the star map, simply touching it to use material components for a spell, or do I need to be holding it? This isn't related to the Guidance or Guiding Bolt spells.
Is, "If you mean wearing it on your belt or something and intend to let go of the quarter staff to grasp the map, that is probably fine," fine according to RAW?

I updated my answer based on your edit to the question, but it might also help to specify in the question what you mean by “wearing” the map. Hope it helps!

By "stars druid" do you mean the Circle of Stars from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything? It's worth clarifying.

No, but you can hold it or use your staff instead
You must be holding an object to use it as a focus; from the Player’s Handbook Spellcasting chapter, under Material Components (emphasis mine):

A spellcaster must have a hand free to access a spell’s material components — or to hold a spellcasting focus — but it can be the same hand that he or she uses to perform somatic components.

So simply touching it isn’t sufficient. If you’re literally wearing the map as clothing, that also doesn’t fit the definition of holding it.
If you mean “wearing it” in the sense of having it tied to your belt or similar, and intend to let go of the quarter staff to grasp the map, that’s fine. It would function the same way as a cleric taking one hand off a warhammer to grasp a holy symbol worn around the neck, for example. (Though as Ryan pointed out in the comments, holy symbols are an exception to the usual magical focus rules: to use it, “the caster must hold it in hand, wear it visibly, or bear it on a shield.” - PHB, page 151.) Narratively this might make less sense, depending on the form the map takes - a standard parchment or cloth map would be hard to unroll and read with one hand. But from a rules perspective you only need to be holding it - how you use it to channel your magic is up to you to describe.
However, since you’re only wishing to use the map as a druidic focus for general Spellcasting, and not for the specific extra benefits of the star map (which also require you to be holding it), you’re in luck, since - as per the Adventuring Gear description in the Player’s Handbook - a druidic focus can include:

a staff drawn whole out of a living tree

Note that the druidic focus staff is more costly than a weapon quarterstaff (5gp vs 2sp) and must be specially prepared. Assuming you find or prepare a suitable staff, though, it can also be your weapon. In this scenario, you don’t even need to let go - not even for spells with somatic components! (My druid player supplies them by drawing runes in the earth with the end of their staff.)

I would add to your answer, since you specifically called out a sword and board cleric, that the rules allow for the cleric to wear their holy symbol as an emblem on their shield.  I don't have a page number for it, but it is in the phb Adventuring Gear section which starts on p148.

@RyanZibell: It's page 151: "To use the [holy] symbol in this way, the caster must hold it in hand, wear it visibly, or bear it on a shield." It allows for simply wearing it visibly too, overriding the typical rules for spellcasting foci.

Thanks @RyanZibell - that’s a good catch! I’ve updated the answer accordingly.
